# Java Object Array - Create a method with empty parameter, returns object array of class Book?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have tried multiple ways to format this and every time I am wrong. What is the proper way to display this code?

Create a method called setupMarket with empty parameter but it will need to return an object array of class Book.

This method will create an object array of class Book of size 4.
Initialize each of the 4 objects where
the first object is book of name “Computer Science”, id 0 and price $50
the second object is book of name “Maths”, id 1 and price $40
the third object is book of name “Biology”, id 2 and price $70
the fourth object is book of name “Computer Science”, id 3 and price $60.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean you tried to "format this" and want to know the "proper way to display this code"? What code are you talking about? Is this a question about how you correctly format your Stackoverflow question or do you not have any code and instead expect us to give it to you (which won't happen btw)?

Comment: Please, show the Book class.

Comment: Please add some info on your attempts. e.g. Code that you have written already.

Comment: Did you create the class `Book` already ? Do you know how to instantiate an Array ? Do you know how to instantiate a `Book` ? Please show what you have tried

Comment: `Book[] setupMarket() {...}`. To format code in a question, paste the code, select the lines and click icon `{}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first sight, i guess this is almost what you need (not tested)

```
public class Book {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int price;
 
    public Book(int id, String name, int price) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
    
    // getters setters
}
```

And your method will be

```
    public Book[] setupMarket() {
        Book[] books = new Book[4];
        books[0] = new Book(0,  “Computer Science”, 50);
        books[1] = new Book(1, “Maths”, 40);
        books[2] = new Book(2, “Biology”, 70);
        books[3] = new Book(3, “Computer Science”, 60);
        return books; 
        
    }
```

Let me know more in comments.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not have Book class then use the above answer. create your class and add the data.
filling the data depends on requirement. you can also check the result given below.
here I am filling data based on String array, which will help you to add more data in future.

Case : When you do not have any Book class.

step :1 => create Book class.

```
class Book{
    String name;
    int id;
    int price;
    public Book(String name, int id, int price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Step :2 => Setup the object with data and return as array.

```
public Book[] setUpMarket() {
        Book[] books = new Book[4];
        /*This is used to default data, used to initialized into object.
         * here java =  [book name], 1 [id], 15 [price]
         *list Info is used to hold the data for individual object
         * separated by ','
         */ 
        String listInfo[] = {"java,1,15","php,2,25"};
        //Loop throw the data and fill the object and add into the array.
        for(int i = 0 ; i < listInfo.length; i++) {
            books[i] = new Book(listInfo[i].split(",")[0],
                    Integer.parseInt(listInfo[i].split(",")[1]),
                    Integer.parseInt(listInfo[i].split(",")[2]););
        }
        //return array
        return books;
    }
```

Case : when you have Book class , use the above method only.

Answer (score 0):

Book Class

```
public enum Book {
    ID0("Computer Science", "$50"),
    ID1("Maths", "$40"),
    ID3("Biology", "$70"),
    ID4("Computer Science", "$80");
    
    private final String desc;
    private final String price;
    
    Book(String desc, String price){
        this.desc = desc;
        this.price = price;
    }
    public String setMarketDesc() {
        return desc;
    }
    public String setMarketPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

Main class

```
public class BookMain{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(Book people: Book.values()) {
            System.out.printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t\n", people, people.setMarketDesc(), people.setMarketPrice());
        }
    }
}
```

Tested and printing

```
    ID0 Computer Science    $50 
    ID1 Maths   $40 
    ID3 Biology $70 
    ID4 Computer Science    $80
```